# Can I do self employment work on B1/B2?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, work

I know this question is very common and I know mostly the answer is a hard NO. But I think my case is special in a way. I would like to come to the USA to do handyman work basically. Therefore I will not be taking away any jobs from US citizens, and I will not be paid from a employer but from my own clients that I find. Handyman isn't required to have any kind of certification in California, only think he needs to follow is that no job can be more then 500$ which that isn't a problem for what I have in mind. And he/she needs to pay taxes which I was thinking to apply for ITIN to pay my taxes, I have got friend in the US who could help me with that.
So I guess the question is can I be self-employed handyman in the USA on B1/B2 visa ?
I apreciace all answers thank you.

Comment: How would this *not* take jobs away from american citizens? How is this special? In short: The answer is a hard no - also in your case. B1 is a ***visitor*** visa, and does not allow you to settle and work in the USA.

Comment: Technically I'm not sure this is a duplicate, as the other answer does not explicitly state the self-employment is illegal. The answer is still a hard NO of course.

Answer (score 3):

When you are self-employed, you are both the employer and the employee. Since it is illegal for an employer to employ someone for work in the US who doesn't have work authorization, I think it follows that it is illegal for you (as the employer) to employ yourself (as an employee) for work in the US if you don't have work authorization.